# Integral $a\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{e^{\frac{x^2}{a^2+x^2}}}{a^2+x^2} \,\operatorname dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

I'm looking to calculate $a\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{e^{\frac{x^2}{a^2+x^2}}}{a^2+x^2} \,\operatorname dx$.

Mathematica10 can't integrate this, but numerical integration gives an answer of 5.50843 for any $a$ I've tried, so I assume that there is an analytic answer to be found.

Is this a standard integral?

Many thanks,

Comment: Have you tried using complex analysis?

Comment: Perhaps try substituting $x=a \tan{\theta}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sub $x=a \tan{\theta}$ and the integral becomes

$$\sqrt{e} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-\frac12 \cos{2 \theta}}$$

which is indeed a standard integral, equal to $\pi \sqrt{e} I_0(1/2) \approx 5.50842977...$, where $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind of zeroth order.

Comment: Very nice. Can you point me to a resource that lists that standard integral? I also need the result for the more general integral where the exponent is to the power +1/2.b.cos2θ, where b is a positive constant.

Comment: @Dave See Formula 9.6.16 in [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_376.htm).